# css file crashes VS2010

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010, crash

I'm working on a new project from another person using MS2010 with MVC3. Everything is fine, but the css file. Once I want to open it from the Solution Explorer, MS2010 crashes.
All other css files are OK.
Restarting the VS doesn't help.
Tried several times with the same result.
Ctrl+Break several times and other voodoo didn't help.
The same crashing happens on another machine.

What's the reason?
I believe VS2010 crashes because of possible CSS code inside that file, that could crash the VS2010 parsing mechanism.
The file's value is about 100kb, it looks weird. Any ideas how to fix this problem? 
Of course I won't change the css file is possible (the styles are from another person) and woudn't prefer to split and split and split that css file in parts to check what part(s) cause the VS crashing. 
Any ideas about possible solutions are highly appreciated.

Comment: Split the file into pieces - see what part is causing the problem.

Comment: Seeing the actual css code would highly help others help diagnose any issues..